# Improve accuracy of Multi-Label Text Classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, text, nlp, multilabel-classification

I'm trying to do a multi-label text classification problem where i am stuck at  a certain accuracy score and not able to improve the accuracy.

So in multi-label classification, I have 35 Categories(Classes) and 192 Sub-Categories(Classes), till now i've tried:

1. Preprocessing: replaced contractions, lowered strings, removed punctuations, lemmatized the data, created some custom regex based on data, ran spell checker and improved the spelling mistakes.
2. TfidfVectorization: I have also tried various combinations of values in tfidf matrix such as having bigrams and trigrams increases my accuracy a little bit.
3. Tried many Classifiers (LinearSVC performing best till now) such as RandomForest, Logistic Regression, LinearSVC, XtraTreeClassifier, MultinomialNB, XGBoost and many more..
4. Also applied GridSearchCV and RandomizedSearchCV on almost all the classifiers.

Now from running a base LinearSVC classifier on the actual data without any customized preprocessing i have came from 45% exact match accuracy to 57% exact match accuracy.

I'm kinda stuck here and not being able to think of any solution to improve the accuracy. My target is to achieve 70% Exact Match accuracy

My vectorizer and parameters looks like this:

```py
classifier = Pipeline([
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word',ngram_range=(1, 3),sublinear_tf =True,max_features=100000)),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(dual=False,multi_class='crammer_singer', max_iter = 1000)))]) ## Creating a pipeline to chain & perform feature engineering and Modelling
```

I have achieved 57% Exact match accuracy, However my target is to achieve 70% 
Would be helpful to know how can i increase the accuracy more efficiently.

Comment: So you have 227 individual class labels you're trying to predict, correct? How much input data do you have for each class, and are they all balanced?

Comment: No actually, i have to predict only 1 at a time i.e either Category or Sub-Category,
So i have 35 and 192 Classes for 2 models.